# Hide image behind transparency

Tags: gimp

I'm using gimp to create some character icons. I need to fill a round border with the image of the character. I can get the character image behind the border, but then the edges of the square character picture stick outside of the border. I have a ton of these to make so I need an easy way to just slide each character picture into the border and then save it off as an icon.

Please see image below for an example of what I'm getting.

Thanks!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a group with a layer mask added. The mask itself is basically a circle.

Here's the construction:

[image]

To replace the character, just paste as a new layer, move it into the layer group and position/scale as required.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!